# Using IF in foreach R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to run a foreach loop in parallel to execute given an IF condition.

I want to look at a list of names of data frames (`data.list`) in my global environment, and print the names as a list of the tables with less than 2 columns.

So far, I have:

```
#This simply creates a vector of strings of names of data tables   
data.list <- ls(pattern=paste("^", dsn[1], sep=""))

registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(cores, type='SOCK', outfile=''))
data.remove <- foreach(i=length(data.list), .combine=c) %dopar% {
  if ((length(get(data.list[i]))<2)==TRUE) {print(data.list[i])}
}
```

But I am not sure if it shouldn't be more like:

```
data.remove <- foreach(i=data.list, .combine=c) %dopar% {
  if ((length(get(i))<2)==TRUE) {print(i)}
}
```

Both do NOT work and say:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'EOADB_PRB.3200.hdd' not found"
```

the object is one of the table names.

Comment: It seems the get() may be the problem, but I am not sure

Comment: The data.frames are not exported to the workers (how should `foreach` know that they are needed?). You need to change your whole approach.

Comment: OK, I vectorized the operation no problem with vapply but, if you don't mind, how you I go about using the foreach. Like you said, the data.frames are not exported. Why? and How do I change that? Thanks

Comment: `foreach(x = mget(data.list), ...`